# pdfpages - a7 and a6 in different orientations cohabitation on one a4

Tags: pdfpages

I have 4 pdf documents I want to merge in one A4 :

- two a7 landscape
- one a6 landscape
- one a6 portrait

I can't have the two a6 pdf rotated landscapewise at once.

This code keeps the 2 a6 as there are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\def\SEM{22}

\includepdfmerge[%
    pages={1},
    nup=2x2,
    frame=true,
%   rotateoversize,
%   landscape,
%   noautoscale
    ]{
    ./Classe_6e/Semaines/6e_Sem_\SEM/6e_Sem_\SEM, % a7 landscape
    ./Classe_5e/Semaines/5e_Sem_\SEM/5e_Sem_\SEM, % a7 landscape
    ./Classe_4e/Semaines/4e_Sem_\SEM/4e_Sem_\SEM, % a6 landscape
    ./Classe_4e/Semaines/4e_Sem_\SEM/4e_Cointer_\SEM} % a6 portrait
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code switches the 2 a6 (landscape to portrait and vice versa) :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\def\SEM{22}

\includepdfmerge[%
    pages={1},
    nup=2x2,
    frame=true,
    rotateoversize,
%   landscape,
%   noautoscale
    ]{
    ./Classe_6e/Semaines/6e_Sem_\SEM/6e_Sem_\SEM, % a7 landscape
    ./Classe_5e/Semaines/5e_Sem_\SEM/5e_Sem_\SEM, % a7 landscape
    ./Classe_4e/Semaines/4e_Sem_\SEM/4e_Sem_\SEM, % a6 landscape
    ./Classe_4e/Semaines/4e_Sem_\SEM/4e_Cointer_\SEM} % a6 portrait
\end{document}
```

[image]